# Converting nested list in Json script to Dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dataframe

```
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY"
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()
data = response.json()["records"]
data = response.json()["records"]['data']
```

I am unable to convert this to a dictionary to a properly structured df.
The Nested Loop is very convolute, can someone please help me out.
[image]

Comment: What is, in your definition, a "properly structured df"?

Comment: In a format like one in th image

Answer (score 0):

So `response.json()` will give you a dict of your data. Now you want to convert it into a dataframe. Pandas does that easily...

```
data = response.json()
df = pd.Dataframe.from_dict(data)
```

Boom. Voila. you just have to decide if you want to map certain fields etc.

Comment: i already tried that.. 
This is a very entabgled list, so this method is not working.

Comment: Then please try and describe what you expected output is?

Comment: see the attached image

Comment: Sorry, not very helpful image that. It's not clear what data you want to use from the API. Have a further look at the arguments for from_dict and the constructor for Dataframe